How to Delete Transactions from a Specific Date/Year in Odoo's Sales, Delivery, Invoice, and Payment Modules?
I am working on an Odoo project and need to clean up transactions from a specific date or year within the Sales, Delivery, Invoice, and Payment modules. The goal is to remove all records that fall within a certain date range without affecting other data.
Here are the details of my setup:
Odoo version: [Your Odoo version]
Modules in use: Sales, Inventory, Invoicing, Accounting
What I've Tried:
Using Odoo's Interface: I attempted to filter and delete records manually through the Odoo interface, but this process is time-consuming and can be error-prone.
Automated Actions: I explored automated actions, but they seem more suited for modifying records rather than bulk deletion.
SQL Queries: I considered running SQL queries directly on the database to remove the records, but I'm concerned about breaking data integrity or missing related records that should also be deleted.
Specific Questions:
What is the safest and most efficient way to delete transactions from a specific date or year in the Sales, Delivery, Invoice, and Payment modules?
Are there any built-in tools or third-party modules in Odoo that facilitate bulk deletion of records by date range?
What precautions should I take to ensure data integrity when performing this operation?
Is there a way to automate this process for future use if needed?
Additional Context:
I have administrator access to the Odoo instance and can perform operations at the database level if necessary. However, I would prefer a method that minimizes the risk of unintended data loss or corruption.
Any advice, guidance, or code snippets would be greatly appreciated!
